# How to Pass a parameter form button click to Jquery Function

Tags: c#, jquery

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string val = TextBox1.Text;
            string location = Server.MapPath(".");
            SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT ISNULL(MAX(MODIFIED_NO),0) FROM FORM_NAME WHERE FRM_NME='" + TextBox1.Text + "'", con);
            con.Open();
            object modifyno = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            con.Close();

    }
```

Here I want to pass the "modifyno" as parameter to Jquery Function

```
function check(modifyno ) {

    if (modifyno == "1") {
        document.getElementById('Autolbl').value = "100";
        document.getElementById('Autotxt').value = "100";
    }
    if (modifyno == "2") {
        document.getElementById('Autolbl').value = "200";
        document.getElementById('Autotxt').value = "200";
    }

}
```

How i can call the function by passing parameters of modifyno...
please help me soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegisterClientScriptBlock("call check", "check(" + modifyno + ");");

Comment: hey Rajneesh, its working now... Actually my controls are in update panel, for that reason its not worked.... i got it bro... Thanks...

Comment: ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "hwa", "check("+modifyno+")", true);

Answer (score 0):

After setting modifyno variable it's value you can use the [RegisterClientScriptBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx) to define your variable in client side.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType, "initVar", string.Format("var modifynoclientvar={0};", modifyno), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a hiddenField. Because you can use the hiddenfield in jquery and C# very easily.

--- Click answered if the my answer really answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Answer

In button Click, just write this code, before writing this , please note that that controls should no be in update panel of ajax.

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "call check", "check("+modifyno+")", true);